# How to import ssl, socket modules in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl

I am new to python. I want to make code that makes ssl client that connects to ssl server. I found thi in python documentation:

```
import socket, ssl

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_default_certs()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname='www.verisign.com')
ssl_sock.connect(('www.verisign.com', 443))
```

However, there is `import ssl, socket`. I found that to import, the .py code for import must be placed in the same directory of the code.

My question: where to download the ssl, socket modules from? where to place them?
In general, how can I import ready-made python modules such as ssl and socket?

Comment: Have you tried to run this code? `ssl` and `sockets` are builtin modules so the code should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is package that you are searching for 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl/1.16

or just pip install ssl

Comment: could you please clarify where do I write this: pip install ssl

Comment: I am a Windows user. I downloaded it. But it contains a lot of files inside. Don't know what to do to make my code sees it?

Comment: write pip install ssl in command prompt and it will automatically download and install package
@user2192774